# Is my proof about diagonalization of a operator right?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, diagonalization

I have the following operator ($P_n$ is the vector space of all polynomials with degree $\leq n$)
$$
D:P_n\rightarrow P_n
$$
Such that $D(p)=p'$

I want to know if this operator is diagonalizable.

**My attempt:** I have that the matrix of representation of $D$ is
$$
A:=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq (n+1)}=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
k-1 &if& i=j=k\\
0&if&i\neq j
\end{array}
\right.
$$
So, the charasteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=\prod_{k=1}^n(k-\lambda)
$$
As each eigenvalues has multiplicity $1$ then $D$ is diaginalizable.
Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your matrix representation is wrong.

In fact $D$ is not disgonalizable, because it has no eigenvalues except $0$, for which the only corresponding eigenvectors are the constant polynomials. (This is clear because if $\lambda\ne0$ and $p\ne0$ then $\deg(Dp)<\deg(p)=\deg(\lambda p)$ so $Dp\ne\lambda p$.)

Comment: I see your point. But I can't see where is my mistake in the matrix $A$. Can you tell me?

Comment: I can't say what your mistake was since you don't show how you obtained the matrix. But saying $a_{k,k}=k-1$ says that $Dx^k=(k-1)x^k$.

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks a lot!!